# Scope of try declared variable

Tags: javascript, scope

Looking at [this code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/multicast/ChatClient.js#L30), in prototype function `onDiagram` *line 30* we have:

```
proto.onDiagram = function (message, address) {
  message = this.arrayBufferToString(message);
  try {
    var obj = JSON.parse(message);
  } catch (e) {
    return;
  }
  if (!obj) {
    return;
  }
  switch (obj.type) {
    ...
```

Would not `obj` be local to `try` here? Would expected the code to be:

```
var obj;
try {
   obj = JSON.parse(message);
} catch (e) {
   ...
```

Comment: In JavaScript, the scope for variables declared in functions is usually the entire function. Some browsers support `let` declaration which would restrict the scope more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would not obj be local to try here?

No. The declaration gets hoisted (as do all declarations) to the top of the execution context. The code is effectively interpreted as you have shown in your second example. Until a value is assigned to `obj` it implicitly has the value `undefined`.

JavaScript (ES5, anyway) does not have block scope so it's not possible to contain a variable declaration to a `try` block. It will always be visible to the enclosing function.

Comment: OK. Thanks, believe I have begotten somewhat side-tracked by JSHint. Did a test now, and it complains about "variable used outside of scope". (Believe it is there I have it from. As in done it myself earlier.) Is it bad practice?

Comment: @Zimzalabim - It can be considered bad practice for the exact reason you asked this question: it's confusing. By declaring the variable outside of the block it makes it easier to work out what's going on at first glance.